# Remove pretty photo style and script if not exist!

Tags: filters, wp-enqueue-script

I need to dequeue or remove style and script related to "pretty_photo" from my theme but load it again only when it **called or needed**

i have this code in my `functions.php`

```
wp_enqueue_style('pretty_photo', MASTER_THEME_DIR . '/addons/prettyphoto/prettyPhoto.css',array() ,false,'all')
```

Comment: Please [edit] this question to provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i don't know more details, all i need is to load pretty photo scripts and styles only if calling in posts. simply I don't need it to load in my home page or other pages. only on blog posts.

Comment: Ok. Single post pages or post archives as well?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to working finally .. The code is:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pretty_photo_styles', 100 );
function pretty_photo_styles() {
   if ( ! is_single() ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'pretty_photo' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'pretty_photo' );
    }
}
```

Please someone correct it if I missed anything! 
I tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, hacking a theme is generally a bad idea unless it is a theme you've built and maintain. I don't know if that applies to you or not.

It sounds like you just need that code to load on single post pages. Technically, this should be fairly simple.  The [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) template tag should do the trick.

```
function conditionally_load_style_wpse_143224() {
  if (is_singular()) {
    wp_enqueue_style(
      'pretty_photo', 
      MASTER_THEME_DIR . '/addons/prettyphoto/prettyPhoto.css',
      array(),
      false,
      'all'
    );
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','conditionally_load_style_wpse_143224');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. but it doesn't work .. Actually i did all optimization to my theme very carefully considering all kind of issues could happen. I did combined some css and js files and made all woocommerce styles and scripts to load only on the related pages and so, i like to do the same with pretty photo. All this work make my site get 100 score at pingdom speed test :) and without any CDN yet. Please check if you like: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cJ5UVH/www.elhafez.com

Comment: If you worked out your own solution, please post it in an "Answer" box that it will help other people in the future.

Comment: No, still doesn't work .. i forgot to minion I'm not hacking the theme, i bought this and just do my own optimization that's allowed from the seller.

Comment: "Altering a theme you don't maintain" is what "hacking the theme" means. It isn't about whether you have rights to the theme, it is about the changes being lost when you update. "It doesn't work" is a meaningless description of the problem.